# JavaScript - document is not defined (Electron)

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to change the background color when the user is pushing a button.

I have two main functions: `darkTheme()` for the dark mode and `lightTheme()` for the light mode.

**JavaScript**

```
function changeAppearence() {
  let themeForPage = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if (themeForPage === 'light'){
    lightTheme();
  } else if (themeForPage === 'dark'){
    darkTheme();
  } else {
    darkTheme();
  }
}

function darkTheme() {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');

  document.getElementById('headerMainMenu').style.backgroundColor = '#212529';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#343a40';
  document.body.style.color = 'white';

}

function lightTheme() {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');

  document.getElementById('headerMainMenu').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  document.body.style.color = 'white';

}
```

But after typing the `npm start` command I get this error:

**Error Message:**

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at darkTheme (/Users/user/Documents/#4_Website_ Development/Electron/electron-app/main.js:76:3)
    at changeAppearence (/Users/user/Documents/#4_Website_ Development/Electron/electron-app/main.js:15:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/#4_Website_ Development/Electron/electron-app/main.js:8:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/Users/user/Documents/#4_Website_ Development/Electron/electron-app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:110:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/#4_Website_ Development/Electron/electron-app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:222:9)
```

I also tried to make a simple `document.body.style.color = 'white';` in the JavaScript file without any function, but I get the same error.

Comment: we would need more info. How are you loading this JS file into the window?

Comment: @pushkin With `<script src="main.js"></script>` at the top of settings.html. I also tried to copy the script in the seetings.html with the normal `script` tag, this works, but I need the script in the `main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling these functions? It looks like you are trying to call them from the main process, which runs in node and doesn't have direct access to the DOM. You can use `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` along with `contextBridge` to communicate btwn the renderer process and the main process, but it's not clear from the context if these functions should be in the main process or not. My initial thought is that these should be within the renderer process exclusively since this only affects the rendering window and not the app globally.